# White list specific chrome extension to access local storage if third party plugin cookies are disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which uses local storage to store a few values which are used in the extension. If a user blocks third-party cookies in chrome settings under (chrome://settings/content/cookies), the extension does not have access to the local storage.

Certain organizations do not allow third party applications to access the cookies(local storage).
The client request is to only white list my extension and allow it to access the local storage without enabling third party cookies, is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simply use the built-in extension storage: [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: @wOxxOm, I am currently using chrome storage, access to it is being disabled (when block third party plugins is enabled) and an error is thrown when I try to get/set a value

Comment: No, this setting doesn't affect `chrome.storage` so your code is doing something else, probably `localStorage`, please post a real [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm You're right, please add this as a comment, will accept. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chrome.storage` instead of `localStorage` API.

As `localStorage` is domain specific and `chrome.storage` is plugin specific and is unaffected by third party settings.